# How to optimize Delphi code for image decoding?

Tags: image, delphi, image-processing

I have encoded images and want to decode them in my program. The images decoding is based on the answer of [Loren Pechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/738901/1615266): the image file is loaded in Stream, decoded, converted to MemoryStream and then loaded from MemoryStream by [TSynPicture class](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2010/03/20/GIF,-TIF,-PNG-and-JPG-pictures-TGraphic-read/write-via-GDI). The Delphi code is the following:

```
function loadEncodedImage(filename, keycode : string) : TBitmap;
  syn : TSynPicture;
  fs  : TFileStream;
  ms  : TMemoryStream;
  buf : AnsiString;
begin
  result := nil;
  try
    fs := TFileStream.Create(filename, fmOpenRead);
    SetLength( buf, fs.Size );
    fs.ReadBuffer( buf[1], fs.Size );

    // ....
    // Here I decode data stored in buf and put it into buf again.
    // ....

    ms := TMemoryStream.Create();
    ms.SetSize( fs.Size );
    ms.WriteBuffer( buf[1], fs.Size );

    syn := TSynPicture.Create();
    syn.LoadFromStream( ms );
    result := syn.ToBitmap;
  finally
    FreeAndNil( fs );
    FreeAndNil( syn );
   end;
end;
```

As you see I use two buffers of memory: **buf** and **TMemoryStream**. How this code can be optimized to avoid double memory use?

Comment: Why is `buf` of type `AnsiString`?

Comment: Because I use this type in decode procedure. I need array of bytes. What type can you propose for this?

Comment: If you need an array of bytes, then an array of bytes should do. ;-) Alternatively use `TBytes`, if you don't like `array of Byte` for some reason.

Comment: I rolled back your edit. There's no need to repeat the answers you got in the question. Do you need more help?

Comment: @ivan then perhaps you should accept what you consider to be the best answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`TMemoryStream` has a `Memory` member allowing directly accessing the memory block. This way you can completely eliminate `buf`.

Comment: Memory is a pointer pointing to the memory. You don't want to change `Memory`, you want to change `Memory^`, or in your case probably `PByteArray(Memory)^`. Note the `^`.

Comment: Like this `Memory^[234]`?

Comment: Yep. You just have to keep in mind that the pointer refers to memory allocated by the `TMemoryStream`.

Comment: It is possible to load a file directly to the TMemoryStream like David Heffernan propose. And to change the data stored in `Memory` I need to use something like this: `PByteArray(Memory)^[k]`?

Comment: @ivan I'm proposing exactly the same as jens

Answer (score 4):

1. Read the encoded images into a memory stream rather than an `AnsiString`. Allow me to say "eugh" at the thought of using an `AnsiString` for this!
2. Decode inplace in the memory stream. You can access the buffer using the `Memory` property of the memory stream.
3. Load the memory stream into the picture object.

It is quite plausible that a `TByteStream` would be a better choice here. That gives you more natural byte-oriented access to the buffer.

For what it is worth, I would anticipate that you will not be able to measure the performance difference obtained by removing the extra memory copy.

Comment: The property is read only. But the property returns a pointer to the memory. You can access them memory through that pointer.

Comment: If I need to get n-th byte, do I need to use this code: `PByteArray(Memory)^[n]`?

Comment: Yes that will work. Or enable POINTERMATH and cast to PByte: PByte(ms.Memory)[i]

Comment: I use Delphi 7 and POINTERMATH is not allowed here. This code is work: `(PAnsiChar(ms.Memory)+i)^ :='x'`. Thank you!